# I have created a MySQL Database in Node.js. how to see if its created?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection ({
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "12345"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
if(err)
console.log("Connected!");
con.query("CREATE DATABSE mySql", function(err, result) {
if(err)
console.log("Database Created");
});
});

Comment: [SHOW DATABASES Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-databases.html)

Comment: I am working in VScode and it's showing an error after writing SHOW DATABASES

Comment: Where did you write it? What error do you get?

Comment: SOHW : The term 'SOHW' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or  
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that     
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ SOHW DATABASES
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SOHW:String) [], CommandNotFoundException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: `SOHW` is a typo. It's `SHOW`

Comment: am writing on VsCODE

Comment: The IDE is unrelated for this.

Comment: SHOW : The term 'SHOW' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that     
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ SHOW DATABASES
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SHOW:String) [], CommandNotFoundException     
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Are you writing this directly into the terminal? If you want to use the terminal for this you have to use the [MySQL command line client](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html). But you can also send a query with this statement.

Comment: SHOW DATABASES is a statement which must be executed as common SELECT query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UI applications to see the database schema/data or whatsoever.

See [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

P.S. You can use raw SQL queries to traverse your database.